# How to buffer/prefetch more than one video on website?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I’m making a website that plays a video, but it also have the option to switch between different videos. The new video will continue at the same timestamp as the old one left of etc. But when switching there is a small delay/lag. Is there a way to buffer or prefetch all the videos so there is no lag?

```
<video preload="auto" class="v1" src="video/v1.mp4"></video>
<video preload="auto" class="v2" src="video/v2.mp4"></video>
<video preload="auto" class="v3" src="video/v3.mp4"></video>
```

Here is some of the jquery code that switches between the videos. (just to give you an idea)

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

        $(".v1,.v2,.v3")[0].play();

        $(".v1,.v2,.v3")[0].muted = true;

        $(".v2,.v3").hide();
        $(".v3,.v2")[0].pause();

        var time = [];

        $(document).keydown(function(e) {

            time.push($(".v1")[0].currentTime);
            time.push($(".v2")[0].currentTime);
            time.push($(".v3")[0].currentTime);

            $(".v3")[0].muted = true;
            $(".v2")[0].muted = true;

            switch(e.which) {
                case 37: // left

                    if(!$(".v2")[0].paused){
                        break;
                    }

                    $(".v1")[0].pause();
                    $(".v2")[0].pause();
                    $(".v3").hide();
                    $(".v2").hide();

                    if(!$(".v3")[0].paused){
                        $(".v3")[0].pause();
                    }

                    $(".v2")[0].play();
                    $(".v2")[0].currentTime = Math.max.apply(Math,time);
                    $(".v2").fadeIn(100);

                    break;
            }

            e.preventDefault(); // prevent the default action (scroll / move caret)
        });
    });
```

Comment: Which browser are you using?  https://caniuse.com/#feat=link-rel-preload  (not clear if this also applies to video preload, but likely)

Comment: Need to work with newest :)

Comment: Newest *what*?  Chrome, IE, Edge, Safari?

Comment: All of the most used browsers, chrome, safari, firefix, edge and ophera.

Answer (score 0):

You have some jquery plugins that can perform what you want.

You can check [BigVideo](http://dfcb.github.io/BigVideo.js/).

In their [example](http://dfcb.github.io/BigVideo.js/example-playlist.html) they have a "Playlist" example where you can change videos as you ask.

Comment: Seams this one is buggy to, but ill try a hostingprovider with compression.